# Merging two tables in SQL Server 2008 R2 to get records based on a condition

Tags: sql-server

table 1

```
ID  Date    Area     message
111 2015-04-23  59   testing
222 2015-04-23  59
333 2015-04-23  97
```

table 2

```
ID  Date    Area    firstname   lastname
111 2015-04-23  67   doe        K
222 2015-04-23  67   jil        M
333 2015-04-23  97   scot       P
```

i have two tables i want it to check the table 1 first if the id exists for the area then it must get me the records from table 1 if the records  doesnt exists in table one it must fetch it from table two however  later on in the day the id might move to a new area which is updated in table 2.

```
if EXISTS (select ID       
           from Table1 
           where area=@Area and Date=convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),10)
           )

BEGIN
 select     t2.ID
            ,Firstname
            ,Lastname
            ,Message
    from Table2 as T2 inner join Table1 T1
         on T2.ID=t1.ID
    where area=@Area and

          and Date=convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),10)


END 
ELSE if not Exists(select ID       
                   from table1 
                   where area=@Area and   Date=convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),10)
                   )

BEGIN
select      ID
           ,Firstname
           ,Lastname
    from  table 2
    where area=@Area

END

END
```

the problem is that because the area changed in table two it thinks that the record for ID 111 doesnt exists in table 1 so its ignoring the first part of the exists

Comment: What is SQL Server r8?

Comment: I think he means SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I assume you are searching the data where the `@Area` value is 67. In this case, of course it won't find ID 111 in `table1`, because that area isn't recorded there. I'm not really clear on what your question is. Are you looking for a way to query `Table2` and retrieve data from `Table1` with the correct `Area` value?

Comment: sorry typo i did mean 2008 r2

Comment: @Aidan im passing the area value as 59.i want it to check if there is records for that area in table1 if there is no records then only it must go to table2

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what left outer join is for? No need for procedural programming in SQL Server. The engine will handle it, that's what a good database model is for:

```
SELECT B.ID, A.FIRSTNAME, A.LASTNAME, B.MESSAGE
FROM [TABLE2] AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN [TABLE1] AS B
ON A.AREA=B.AREA
AND A.DATE=B.DATE
```

If you struggle with the distinctions between joins, I would read up on [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/). The ven diagrams are great for visualising how it works.

Comment: no if the id already exists in table 1 then i require certain fields,sometimes there is no records in table 1 ,then only i want to go to table 2 and retrieve different fields

Comment: Yes but the issue is you're passing 59 as the @AREA variable, but there is no 59 in table2 in your definition, so both queries will return zero matches.

Comment: thats what i want it to ignore the table 2 area of 67 but give me the the firstname and last name column.as long as i get the area 59 from table 1 and must give me the columns from table 2 that go with the id.

Comment: let me join it on area and see